# How to calculate conditional sum?

Tags: excel

In MS Excel, I can use `sum(A1:A5)` to compute the sum of some cells.

How to put a condition to the cells? E.g.  "if Ai > 1000, then consider Ai to the sum, otherwise ignore it".

100
1100
1200
900
1200

Then the `sum(A1:A5) = 3500`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `sumif` aggregating function, described [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010062465.aspx).

It even gives a very close example to what you want:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B25,">5")
```

which you should be able to morph for your purposes into:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A5,">1000")
```

The image below has a simple sum in `B7` and the `sumif` variant shown above in `B8`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's Worth briefly mentioning as well the SUMIFS function that allows you to put several conditions on the sum.

```
= SUMIFS(SUm_Range, Condition Range 1, Condition 1, Condition Range 2, Condition 2...)
```

And the similar function COUNTIF(s), Averageif(s), etc.

Obviously, if you want to have a condition that depends on another cell, just concatenate

Example, if you want to sum only numbers in column A greater than the value that is in cell B1:

```
=SUMIF($A:$A,">"&B1)
```